# Multiple groups in ldap device authenticatable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to allow users to login who are present in group1 or group2
but during LDAP authorization it is checking in both groups.

If user is present in either group1 or group2 i need to allow them to login.

Can anybody assist on this?

In devise.rb

> config.ldap_check_group_membership = true

**In ldap.yml**

```
 authorizations: &AUTHORIZATIONS

  group_base: ou=groups,dc=test,dc=com

 required_groups:

  cn=admins,ou=groups,dc=test,dc=com -----group1

  cn=users,ou=groups,dc=test,dc=com ----- group2

require_attribute:

# objectClass: inetOrgPerson
# authorizationRole: postsAdmin

development:
  host: # ip address is to be filled in here..
  port: # port number goes here..
  attribute: cn 
  base: # my tree base details go in here..
  admin_user: cn=admin_name,dc=test,dc=com
  admin_password: # password goes in here..
  ssl: true 
  <<: *AUTHORIZATIONS
```

Comment: Perhaps a silly question, but are all admins users as well? If so, you can remove one of the requirements. Or add the admins to users and remove the admin groups. As long as you have both groups in the requires section, it will require membership to both.

Answer (score 1):

/devise_ldap_authenticatable-0.8.3/lib/devise_ldap_authenticatable/ldap/connection.rb

```
def in_required_groups?
    return true unless @check_group_membership

    ## FIXME set errors here, the ldap.yml isn't set properly.
    return false if @required_groups.nil?

    arr_res = []
    for group in @required_groups
      if group.is_a?(Array)
        res = in_group?(group[1],group[0])
        arr_res << res
      #  return false unless in_group?(group[1], group[0])
      else
        return false unless in_group?(group)
      end
    end
    DeviseLdapAuthenticatable::Logger.send(arr_res)
    return true if arr_res.include? true
   # return true
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Only 4 months late but for anyone still facing this, you can monkey patch a single method in the gem

```
module Devise
  module LDAP
    class Connection
      def in_required_groups?
        found = false
        return true unless @check_group_membership
        return false if @required_groups.nil?
        for group in @required_groups
          if group.is_a?(Array)
            found = true if  in_group?(group[1], group[0])
            # return false unless in_group?(group[1], group[0])
          else
           found = true if in_group?(group)
            # found = true if  in_group?(group[1], group[0])
          end
        end
        return found
      end
    end
  end
end
```